# Historical Daily NAV for Closed End Funds

Tags: yahoofinance, funds

Does anyone know where to get historical, daily net asset values for closed end funds from the date of inception to the present?  Yahoo finance has daily opening, high, low, closing values, but no NAV that I'm aware of through their YQL service (querying yahoo.finance.historicaldata).

At a minimum, I would like to know the NAV of a fund on the date the dividend is paid.

Answer (score 4):

On the website interface, you can get a CEF's NAV by circumfixing X-...-X (prefix & suffix) to the ticker. For example, the NAV time series ticker corresponding to the PDI price series is XPDIX. Or, XBTZX (NAV), BTZ (price). That might work for you.

Comment: This is correct, also some CEF's with 2 letter tickers are weird i.e. GF becomes XGFNX

Comment: That _is_ weird. Is the extra letter (here it's 'N') predictable?

Comment: I couldn't find the corresponding NAV for CH or FT, so I am not sure.

Comment: Adding the X before and after the ticker doesn't work for me! Is this broken?

Comment: I notice that TY becomes XTYCX for the NAV.  Not sure why the "C".  TY is Tri-Continental.  When you start typing Tri-Continental into the Yahoo search box, you can see the XTYCX ticker come up.  So searching for the name of the fund or starting the the search with an "X" preceding the symbox (e.g. "XTY") may help find the NAV symbol.