# Historical Daily/Monthly NAV for Closed End Funds - known duplicate but unanswered previously

Tags: equities, time-series, programming

Using this query

```
https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20("SDV.L")&format=xml&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys
```

I can get the basic price today of SDV* (and high. low, volume, last close price, etc.) in XML, JSON, etc..

Does anyone know a currently working way of retrieved this data in XML, JSON, a webservice etc. from Yahoo or elsewhere (for free, or with a free, ideally, or on a long, trial - the free data can be wrong or corrupted, or absent in places until I pay).

I am aware of

[Historical Daily NAV for Closed End Funds](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/16949/historical-daily-nav-for-closed-end-funds)

and I tried replacing SDV.L with XSDVX.L or XSDV.LX above but both returned empty XML, accept for the quote symbol?

- Chelverton Small Companies Dividend Trust PLC on the UK LSE

Comment: Were you able to find an answer to this question?