# Data Sources/Vendors for Closed End Fund NAV data

Tags: data-source, quandl

I am seeking NAV pricing for closed end funds as a data source. Listed CEFs are required to disclose NAV once every quarter at the least, and many disclose daily at the most.

I do see a previous question [asking a similar question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/16949/historical-daily-nav-for-closed-end-funds) but I would prefer a non-html source, and am happy to pay a fee but it's been difficult information to find. Also I believe Yahoo Finance API is dead now?

Currently I have tried using Quandl's [End of Day US Stock Price](https://www.quandl.com/data/EOD-End-of-Day-US-Stock-Prices) package, but for most funds I have tried, it contains only the NAV as of April 28th, 2017 which I also found strange.

Seems this data is either not very popular or not very easy to get?